# EF4.1 + MARS - New Transaction Not Allowed on UPDATE

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am getting the following exception when I am updating an entity in my database:

> New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session.

I use the same block of code to process all of the incoming data (being scraped from an Excel workbook). The only difference between the working INSERT and the not working UPDATE is the following:

```
public void UploadWorkbook(Workbook workbook, string uploadedBy, string comments)
{
    workbook.UploadedBy = uploadedBy;
    workbook.Comments = comments;

    var existing = _repository.Get(x => x.FileName == workbook.FileName);
    if (existing == null)
        _repository.Insert(workbook); // this works on the commit
    else
        _repository.Update(workbook); // this causes commit to fail

    _unitOfWork.Commit(); // fails when repository runs update method
}
```

Also, here is the update method:

```
public override void Update(Workbook entity)
{
    var existing = Get(x => x.FileName == entity.FileName);

    if (existing == null)
    {
        var message = string.Format(@"Error :: Cannot update Workbook '{0}' 
                                    because it does not exist in the database.", 
                                    entity.FileName);

        throw new Exception(message);
    }

    existing.Version = entity.Version;
    existing.DateModified = DateTime.Now;
    existing.Comments = entity.Comments;
    existing.FilePath = entity.FilePath;

    if (existing.Data != null)
        existing.Data.Clear();

    existing.Data = entity.Data;
}
```

Here is the implementation of the Get method:

```
public virtual T Get(Func<T, bool> where)
{
    return _dbSet.Where(where).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I have looked at some other posts here regarding a similar issue but nothing quite like what I am experiencing. I am really stuck here as I can't make much sense out of how an INSERT works but an UPDATE fails.. if there was another transaction going wouldn't that cause either action to fail?

Comment: How do you handle lifetime of your context / repositories / sets? How many concurrent operations are you running?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka The lifetime of my context and repositories is per HTTP request and I am running no concurrent operations I can think of. The only reason I have MARS enabled is for lazy loading and executing nested queries to avoid the "there is already an open data reader" exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first suspicion would be that your Get call

```
Get(x => x.FileName == entity.FileName);
```

implicitly creates a new thread/transaction that is not closed prior to committing the unit of work.  Then your unit of work is attempting to create a brand new transaction in the call to commit, which conflicts with the already open Get() transaction.

If this is the case, then you probably want to figure out how to have your Get call operate in the same transaction as your commit call.

**Edit:**

I believe you may be able to fix your problem by simply changing

```
public virtual T Get(Func<T, bool> where)
{
    return _dbSet.Where(where).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

to

```
public virtual T Get(Func<T, bool> where)
{
    return _dbSet.Where(where).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

`SingleOrDefault()` should force the sequence to finish being "read" and free up the connection for the commit transaction.  (It also may be safer to begin with, since if your query ever returned more than one result, it is not clear from `FirstOrDefault()` which record you would actually get, since no ordering is specified.  Using `SingleOrDefault()` will throw an exception in the event that more than one row is returned)

Or you could try an explicit transaction scope:

```
public void UploadWorkbook(Workbook workbook, string uploadedBy, string comments)
{
    workbook.UploadedBy = uploadedBy;
    workbook.Comments = comments;

    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope())
    {
        var existing = _repository.Get(x => x.FileName == workbook.FileName);
        if (existing == null)
            _repository.Insert(workbook); // this works on the commit
        else
            _repository.Update(workbook); // this causes commit to fail

        _unitOfWork.Commit(); // fails when repository runs update method
        transaction.Complete();
    }
}
```

(see also the [Microsoft Connect page on this error message](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/612369/misleading-error-message-in-sqlexception-when-using-entity-framework))

Comment: thanks for your response. I have added the implementation of my `Get()` method above.

Comment: I see your implementatino of Get(), but I think a little more detail is needed: what is the type of "_dbSet" and how does it get initialized?

Comment: _dbSet is of type `IDbSet<T>` and is initialized in the Repository constructor as `_dbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();` which I have overridden to return an `IDbSet<T>` instead of a `DbSet<T>`. Also, the repository takes a DatabaseFactory to create the DbContext.

Comment: added additional detail in response to your comments.

Comment: I have updated my `Get()` method to use `SingleOrDefault()` but am still getting the same error. Also, I would prefer to avoid the `TransactionScope()` as it requires enabling DTC. do you have any other sugguestions? I should also note I have a OLEDB DataReader used to scrape the Excel file, but it doesn't make a difference if I dispose it before or after the `_unitOfWork.Commit()`, I still get the same exception.